# js scripts not loading on Git Hub Page

Tags: javascript, github-pages

I have the following index github page but the js scripts won't load.

In my index.html, I have the following js script tag:

```
<script src="/js/navbar.js"></script>
```

However, my Github page won't load it properly. 

You can view the error result via this link:

https://coddielam.github.io/JohnManganaroConstruction/

Please help me take a look. Thanks!

repo link:

https://github.com/Coddielam/JohnManganaroConstruction

Comment: Sorry, this question is unclear even after referring to the referenced link. Please elaborate?

Comment: Hi @ToadfishI have just edited my post. I hope that makes my question clearer. Sorry about that.

Comment: It would be best to provide the relevant error from the first link in a code block, and extract the relevant part of the code from your repo and paste it in another code block beow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, you are trying to access https://coddielam.github.io/js/navbar.js, which doesn't exist.

You need to change `/js/navbar.js` to `js/navbar.js`, so that the URL resolves to https://coddielam.github.io/JohnManganaroConstruction/js/navbar.js. The extra `/` at the start tells the browser to look for the file at the root of the website.

Comment: Thank you! Does that mean I will have to do the same for my other urls links in all the other files as well? Like urls to images etc.

Comment: @EddieLam Yes, or you could insert `<base href="JohnManganaroConstruction">` in the `<head>` section of your HTML, so that you don't need `JohnManganaroConstruction` in the links.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @EddieLam Wait, I made a mistake, please read my updated answer. Also, please remove `<base href="JohnManganaroConstruction">`.

Comment: Do you need a base href at all. I am assuming the reason why you don't need that is because github will make that it automatically already?

Comment: @EddieLam By default, the base is the current directory. The `<base>` tag allows you to change the base directory.